# ¿Cómo ahorrar lineas de codigo instanciando muchas interfaces de Room en una clase?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, interface, room

Tengo muchas tablas en ROOM, que a la vez tengo que instanciar cada Interface en cada Activity que se van a utilizar y al momento de cambiar algun dato de una tabla, tengo que cambiar muchos datos en muchos archivos y ya me encontre con el problema que se me pasa modificar alguna y genera errores y tengo que buscar y corregir...

Necesito saber si se puede por ejemplo instanciar todas las tablas en una clase y solo cargar esa clase en la activity.

El siguiente codigo es para instanciar las DB

```
@Database(
    entities = [
        Empleados::class,
        AperturaCaja::class,
        Ticket::class,
        TicketProducto::class,
        Salidas::class,
        Entradas::class,
        MateriaPrima::class,
        Consumibles::class,
        CategoriasProducto::class,
        Productos::class,
        ProductoMateriaprima::class,
        PrecioProductos::class,
        PrecioMateriaPrima::class
    ],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class InstanceDB: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun empleadosDAO(): EmpleadosDAO
    abstract fun aperturaCajaDAO(): AperturaCajaDAO
    abstract fun ticketDAO(): TicketDAO
    abstract fun ticketProductoDAO(): TicketProductoDAO
    abstract fun salidasDAO(): SalidasDAO
    abstract fun entradasDAO(): EntradasDAO
    abstract fun materiaPrimaDAO(): MateriaPrimaDAO
    abstract fun consumiblesDAO(): ConsumiblesDAO
    abstract fun categoriasProductoDAO(): CategoriasProductoDAO
    abstract fun productosDAO(): ProductosDAO
    abstract fun productoMateriaprimaDAO(): ProductoMateriaprimaDAO
    abstract fun precioProductosDAO(): PrecioProductosDAO
    abstract fun precioMateriaPrimaDAO(): PrecioMateriaPrimaDAO

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: InstanceDB? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): InstanceDB {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if(tempInstance != null){
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    InstanceDB::class.java,
                    "tpv_android"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El sigueinte codigo es de una activity donde cargo las tablas para mostrar la informacion... Todavia faltan muchas lineas de codigo donde voy a utilizar a todas las tablas y sus funciones pero me gustaria que fuera un poco mas compacto, legible y organizado

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    lateinit var empleadosDAO: EmpleadosDAO
    lateinit var aperturaCajaDAO: AperturaCajaDAO
    lateinit var ticketDAO: TicketDAO
    lateinit var ticketProductoDAO: TicketProductoDAO
    lateinit var salidasDAO: SalidasDAO
    lateinit var entradasDAO: EntradasDAO
    lateinit var materiaPrimaDAO: MateriaPrimaDAO
    lateinit var consumiblesDAO: ConsumiblesDAO
    lateinit var categoriasProductoDAO: CategoriasProductoDAO
    lateinit var productosDAO: ProductosDAO
    lateinit var productoMateriaprimaDAO: ProductoMateriaprimaDAO
    lateinit var precioProductosDAO: PrecioProductosDAO

    private val itemTicketViewModel: ItemTicketViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val instance = InstanceDB.getInstance(this)
        empleadosDAO = instance.empleadosDAO()
        aperturaCajaDAO = instance.aperturaCajaDAO()
        ticketDAO = instance.ticketDAO()
        ticketProductoDAO = instance.ticketProductoDAO()
        salidasDAO = instance.salidasDAO()
        entradasDAO = instance.entradasDAO()
        materiaPrimaDAO = instance.materiaPrimaDAO()
        consumiblesDAO = instance.consumiblesDAO()
        categoriasProductoDAO = instance.categoriasProductoDAO()
        productosDAO = instance.productosDAO()
        productoMateriaprimaDAO = instance.productoMateriaprimaDAO()
        precioProductosDAO = instance.precioProductosDAO()

        val preferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("empresa", MODE_PRIVATE)
        var productosMenu: MutableList<Productos> = mutableListOf()
        var extrasMenu: MutableList<Extras> = mutableListOf()
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            productosMenu = productosDAO.getAllWhitPrice()
            extrasMenu = materiaPrimaDAO.getAllWhitPrice()
        }

        val formato = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
        val dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols()
        dfs.currencySymbol = ""
        (formato as DecimalFormat).decimalFormatSymbols = dfs

        registerForContextMenu(binding.lvTicket)

        val menuProductos: List<String> = listOf("Productos", "Extras")
        val arrayAdapterMenu =
            ArrayAdapter(applicationContext, R.layout.item_spinner_login, menuProductos)
        (binding.listMenuProductos.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.setAdapter(arrayAdapterMenu)

        lateinit var arrayAdapterProductos: ArrayAdapter<*>
        (binding.listMenuProductos.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    arrayAdapterProductos = GridViewProductos(applicationContext, productosMenu)
                }
                1 -> {
                    arrayAdapterProductos = GridViewExtras(applicationContext, extrasMenu)
                }
            }
            binding.gvProductos.adapter = arrayAdapterProductos
        }
        (binding.listMenuProductos.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.setText(
            (binding.listMenuProductos.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.getAdapter()!!.getItem(0).toString(), false)
        arrayAdapterProductos = GridViewProductos(applicationContext, productosMenu)
        binding.gvProductos.adapter = arrayAdapterProductos

        val arrayAdapterTicket = ListViewTicket(applicationContext, itemTicketViewModel.listaItemsTicket, itemClickCallback = fun(boton: String, id: Int) {
            when(boton){
//                "eliminar" -> itemTicketViewModel.removerItems(id)
//                "restar" -> itemTicketViewModel.restItems(id)
//                "editar" -> showCustomDialogEditItem(id)
            }
        })

        itemTicketViewModel.itemsTicket.observe(this, Observer {
            binding.lvTicket.adapter = arrayAdapterTicket
            binding.btnCobrar.text = getText(R.string.btn_cobrar).toString() + " " + formato.format(itemTicketViewModel.totalVenta())
        })

        binding.gvProductos.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val producto = productosMenu[position]
            itemTicketViewModel.addItems(position.toLong(), producto.nombre, producto.precio!!, producto.tipo!!)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateContextMenu(menu: ContextMenu, v: View, menuInfo: ContextMenuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo)
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu_item_ticket, menu)
    }
    override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val info = item.menuInfo as AdapterContextMenuInfo
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.eliminarItem -> {
                itemTicketViewModel.removerItems(info.id.toInt())
                true
            }
            else -> super.onContextItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En Kotlin no lo he hecho nunca, en Java (la instancias de los DAO) las usas directamente en una clase repositorio, para cada clase debes tener un repositorio al que invocas desde un viewModel para un fragment.
Mi consejo es que las instancias de los DAO las obtengas sólo donde realmente las vayas a necesitar.

Comment: Si entiendo, solo que en 3 o 4 activity estoy utilizando todos los DAO por en una cargo toda la informacion desde mysql en un servidor, en otra actualizo la mayoria de la informacion, en otra hago las "ventas" y se utiliza todas las tablas... y siento que apenas voy a la mitad de la app y ya se me hace demasiado codigo. Apenas estoy viendo lo del MVVM y creo que esa es mi respuesta para tener mas organizado mi codigo... ya veremos en unos dias a ver que sucede

Comment: Si sólo tienes Activities...tu código va a estar muy cargado, deberías usar fragments cuando te sea posible. Suerte.

Comment: independiente de las activities o los fragments que por el momento no veo necesidad de agregar fragments porque no tengo partes de intefaz "reutilizable", no me sirve esta informacion para mejorar y compactar mi codigo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tengo muchas tablas en ROOM, que a la vez tengo que instanciar cada
> Interface en cada Activity

No, no tienes que instanciar cada interface porque la base de datos siempre retorna la misma instancia de los DAOs.

Sólo necesitas crear una instancia de `InstanceDB` (muy mal nombrada por cierto) y luego acceder a los DAOs directamente por sus métodos. Por ejemplo puedes almacenar la base de datos así

```
private val db by lazy { InstanceDB.getInstance(this) }
```

y ejecutar las consultas así

```
db.empleadosDAO().query1()
db.empleadosDAO().query2()
```

de todos modos se crea sólo un objeto `EmpleadosDAO` que ejecuta ambas consultas.

Incluso puedes ahorrarte los paréntesis si en la clase `InstanceDB` los declaras como propiedades en vez de métodos

```
abstract class InstanceDB: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val empleadosDAO: EmpleadosDAO
    abstract val aperturaCajaDAO: AperturaCajaDAO
    ...
}
```

esto te permitirá ejecutar las consultas con esta sintaxis

```
db.empleadosDAO.query1()
```

Y si tampoco quieres escribir el `db.` puedes usar [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) como `apply` o `run`. Ejemplo:

```
db.apply {
    empleadosDAO.query1()
    empleadosDAO.query2()
    aperturaCajaDAO.query1()
}
```

Como ves, **no hay ninguna razón para crear una variable por cada DAO**. Si aún quieres ahorrar más código investiga sobre [inyección de dependencias](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android).

Y deberías tomar los consejos que te dieron en los comentarios. Una activity sólo debería usarse como punto de entrada de tu app. Cosas como consular una base de datos normalmente se hacen en un repositorio, nunca en una activity. En lo posible, el código para la UI tampoco debería estar ahí. Si bien antes se creaba una activity para cada pantalla, ahora se considera mala práctica debido al acomplamiento con el framework y a las inconsistencias entre versiones del sistema. Hay mejores alternativas como fragments o las nuevas [composable functions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose). Te recomiendo leer la [guía de arquitectura](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide).

Comment: Excelente informacion, voy a revisar todo lo que comentas. Tengo 2 meses aprendiendo y programando a la vez en Android y Kotlin. Agradezco tu tiempo y conocimientos